# Moq Generic Repository Pattern

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, moq, nunit-3.0

I have a generic services which are calling generic repository. I need to manage unit test, but not able to do it. May you help me ?

```
public class EntityService<TEntity> : IEntityService<TEntity> where TEntity : class,  new()
{
    private readonly IRepositoryAsync<TEntity> _repository;

    public EntityService(IRepositoryAsync<TEntity> repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    public virtual IQueryable<TEntity> Entities => Queryable();
    public virtual bool Delete(object id)
    {
        if (id == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(id));

        TEntity entity = _repository.Find(id);

        if (entity != null)
            return Delete(entity);

        return false;
    }
}
```

**GENERIC REPOSITORY**

```
public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepositoryAsync<TEntity> where TEntity : class,  new()
{
    private readonly IDataContextAsync _context;
    private readonly DbSet<TEntity> _dbSet;

    public Repository(IDataContextAsync context)
    {
        _context = context ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));

        if (context is DbContext dbContext)
            _dbSet = dbContext.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public virtual void Delete(object id)
    {
        TEntity entity = _dbSet.Find(id);
        Delete(entity);
    }
}
```

What I tried is next:

I had create abstract generic test

```
public abstract class EntityServiceUnitTests<TEntity> where TEntity : class, IEntity,new()
{
    private readonly IEntityService<TEntity> _service;

    public EntityServiceUnitTests()
    {
        _service = CreateSystemUnderTest();
    }

    [Test]
    [TestCase("299cd2b5-ab47-4006-9a47-c85e4770e9b1")]
    public void Delete_EntityWithExistUniqueIdentifier_ReturnsTrue(Guid id)
    {
        bool response = _service.Delete(id);

        Assert.True(response);
    }

    protected abstract IEntityService<TEntity> CreateSystemUnderTest();
}
```

Than I had implement concrete for unit test

```
public class ConcreteEntityServiceUnitTests : EntityServiceUnitTests<Data>
{
    protected override IEntityService<Data> CreateSystemUnderTest()
    {
        MockBehavior behavior = MockBehavior.Strict;

        Mock<IRepositoryAsync<Data>> repoMock = new Mock<IRepositoryAsync<Data>>(behavior);

        repoMock.Setup(s => s.Queryable()).Returns(DataList().AsQueryable);

        SetupService();

        IEntityService<Data> entityService = new EntityService<Data>(repoMock.Object);

        return entityService;
    }

    private void SetupService()
    {
        Mock<IEntityService<Data>> service = new Mock<IEntityService<Data>>();
        service.Setup(s => s.Find(It.Is<Data>(f => f.Id == It.IsAny<Guid>()))).Returns(DataList().FirstOrDefault(w => w.Id == It.IsAny<Guid>()));
    }

    private IList<Data> DataList()
    {
        List<Data> dataList = new List<Data>();
        dataList.Add(new Data
        {
            Id = new Guid("299cd2b5-ab47-4006-9a47-c85e4770e9b1"),
            ObjectState = ObjectState.Added
        });
        dataList.Add(new Data
        {
            Id = new Guid("229cd2b5-ab47-4006-9a47-c85e4770e9b1"),
            ObjectState = ObjectState.Added
        });
        return dataList;
    }
}
```

As error I'm getting:

```
Moq.MockException :  
IRepository<Data>.Find([299cd2b5-ab47-4006-9a47-c85e4770e9b1])
invocation failed with mock behavior Strict.
```

Comment: Seems you are setting up the wrong method, instead of on the repository you are setting up on the service... Then when you invoke the service it tries to invoke the repository which doesn't have setup but mock behaviour is strict...

Comment: Can you give me guidelines how to manage test for repository and for service?

Comment: Be clear with what is the scope of your testing, here the system under test is service, so you only mock the repository and test the service. The repository itself you test from a different unit test...there you mock underlying dependencies of the repository...

Comment: For sure there are no doubts that for them I need two separetelly unit tests. I Understand now that here now it is testing service, may you help me to manage setup correctly for both?

Comment: In your example, you are testing the service so you should mock only the repository `Find` method... `SetupService` is useless in this example, remove it...

Comment: Thanks, was able to now to manage on correct way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207429/discussion-between-danijel-boksan-and-johnny).